# Trigger a ListViewItem Behavior on Property Change?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, windows-store-apps, behavior

I have a **Custom Behavior** attached to my ListViewItems that triggers on **Loaded** and DataContextChanged.

What this behavior does is traverse the VisualTree and by determining its **direct parents**, set the **Visibility** to **Visible** or **Collapsed**.

On initial load, and whenever I add / remove a ListViewItem to the ListView, it works properly.

However, some interactions only changes the **Property** of the ViewModel that is binded to the ListViewItem. What I want to do is, whenever this property changes, I want to **still trigger the custom behavior that set Visibility** for that ListViewItem only. Since the DataContext and Loaded doesn't trigger, my behavior doesn't happen.

Is there a way to do this?

This is my code for reference:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate_Item">
        <Grid x:Name="Grid_TemplateRoot">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Dovetail_UI_Register_Controls_Behaviors:SetItemVisibilityBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Path="ItemName"}
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And the behavior:

```
public class OnLoadedOrDatacontextChangedBehavior<T> : OnLoadedBehavior<T> where T : FrameworkElement
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        TypedAssociatedObject.Loaded += ChangeVisibility();
        TypedAssociatedObject.AddDataContextChangedHandler(OnDataContextChanged);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        TypedAssociatedObject.Loaded -= ChangeVisibility();
        TypedAssociatedObject.RemoveDataContextChangedHandler(OnDataContextChanged);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        ChangeVisibility();
    }

    private void ChangeVisibility()
    {
    //Change visibility here
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How general is this supposed to be?  Can your bound data contexts all implement some interface, so that in your `OnDataContextChanged` you can use `IMyInterface context = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as IMyInterface` and then attach handlers for the property changed events, as well?

Comment: This is for a specific ListView only. Sorry, I'm a bit new at this, what do you mean attach handlers to property changed events? Is it different from INotifyPropertChanged of the ViewModel? Thanks

Comment: If you have control over what is being bound, and your view models _are_ using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then you could update what I had as `INotifyPropertyChanged context = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as INotifyPropertyChanged; context.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => ChangeVisibility();` for instance.

Comment: Great! I tested it and it works! One thing I noticed is that I have other properties that does RaisePropertyChanged... Is it possible that I only listen to when a specific property is changed and not all properties?

Comment: I figured it out! Just implemented my method like this: private void SeatOrCourseNumberChanged(object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) and called it like this: var vm = TypedAssociatedObject.DataContext as CheckItemViewModel;
                    vm.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => SeatOrCourseNumberChanged(s, e);

Could you reply your comment as a Reply so I can mark it as Answer? Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi Mike, it's actually a custom code that we developed so I think just need to mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not publishing this as a class library that needs to support data context coming in as any object whatsoever, then you can update your handler to listen for those property changes on your data context.

For example:

```
protected virtual void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ChangeVisibility();

    // Listen for any further changes which effect visibility.
    INotifyPropertyChanged context = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    context.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => ChangeVisibility();
}
```

You could additionally extend this further, for example if your handler methods for data context changing use `DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler`, then you could cleanup that `PropertyChanged` handler.  Also, you can watch for only specific properties in your `PropertyChanged` handler.  Expanded example:

```
protected virtual void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler args)
{
    ChangeVisibility();
    INotifyPropertyChanged context;

    // Cleanup any handler attached to a previous data context object.
    context = e.OldValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if (context != null)
        context.PropertyChanged -= DataContext_PropertyChanged;

    // Listen for any further changes which effect visibility.
    context = e.NewValue as INotifyPropertyChanged;
    if (context != null)
        context.PropertyChanged += DataContext_PropertyChanged;
}

private void DataContext_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyTargetProperty")
    {
        ChangeVisibility();
    }
}
```